$state run in svelte 5 is narrowing type
I have a filter variable of type "all" | "active" | "completed", which I initialize to 'all'
(in fact it's reactive, declared with $state('all') but I can reproduce the issue with a plain variable
so this works OK:
  let filter: "all" | "active" | "completed" = "all"; // same thing happens if I use $state("all")

  function filteredFn() {
    console.log({ filter }); // => (property) filter: "all" | "active" | "completed"
    if (filter === "active") return todos.filter((t) => !t.completed); // OK!
    if (filter === "completed") return todos.filter((t) => t.completed); //OK!
    return todos;
  }

but if I try to do the same in side a $derived.by() rune, filter is assumed to be of type 'all' as if it were declared with as const, like this:
  let filter: "all" | "active" | "completed" = "all";

  let filtered = $derived.by(() => {
    console.log({ filter }); // => (property) filter: "all" !!!! WRONG!!!

    if (filter === "active") return todos.filter((t) => !t.completed);
    // This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types '"all"' and '"active"' have no overlap.ts(2367)
    if (filter === "completed") return todos.filter((t) => t.completed);
    // This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types '"all"' and '"completed"' have no overlap.ts(2367)
    return todos;
  });

I can fix it with:
let filter = "all" as "all" | "active" | "completed";

or with the $state rune:
let filter = $state<"all" | "active" | "completed">("all");

but I don't know why it doesn't work the same way it works with regular functions
It this a bug or am I missing something???

Your last code snippet seems to be the correct way to do this ($state<T>()). What code did you try with $state that did not work earlier?

I tried with this, but the error also shows up with a plain "all" value, that's why I removed it from the example
let filter: "all" | "active" | "completed" = $state("all");
Anyway, for clarity I'll add it to the question

The problem should be control flow analysis.
If the variable is not changed anywhere, its type is narrowed to just that single value. This happens more often with a regular $derived since that does not even have a function scope, so more aggressive analysis is possible.
As soon as you e.g. have a binding to filter or set it somewhere in the <script> the issue should disappear.
TS Playground demo

thanks a lot, great explanation, and really clear ts playground as well
I imagine the problem is that I'm updating the variable with bind:filter from the markup, and ts has no idea about it, so it assumes the variable is never changed, and narrows it down to the initial value.

When I used a binding, the error went away for me. If it does not go away, that might be a Svelte language tools issue. (Make sure you are using the latest versions.)

just out of curiosity, why is the export {} needed to isolate the filter variable?
how can I change it form the outside without it?

Without the export, the script is considered to be a regular JS script rather than a module. In a regular script all top level variables are declared in the global scope. So any other script could potentially change the variables.
